# Gmail: Email Signature too Long: Under 10,000 Characters

Tags: email, gmail, signature

Hey I've created an email signature, and keep getting errors saying its too long even though it shouldn't be.

Here is the URL of a signature. It works for some people sometimes but also doesn't work other times.

No idea what what the issue is if anyone can take a look.

https://v99email.site/test/test.html

https://v99email.site/uforiasignaturejoreed/uforiasignaturejoreed.html

Any help would be amazing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to convert your business card type signature into an actual image.

This image would then be used as the signature for your emails.

Comment: Hmmm we could try cutting this into less pieces. The social icons would be the only issue with that.